# Как заморозить телеграмм бота при выполнение функции Python

Tags: python, telebot

*Возможно телеграмм апи предусматривает данный метод, но я не могу найти его.*

Мне нужно сделать так,  чтобы когда юзер нажал кнопку, бот в это время начинает обрабатывать функцию, но юзер в это время не может нажимать другие кнопки, точнее он сможет но бот не будет это обрабатывать, как это сделать?

```
юзер нажал кнопку --> обработка and бот не обрабатывает другую информацию
```

Comment: Нужно где-то хранить инфу, что идет обработка и в функция-обработчиках команд не отправлять юзеру ничего. Для python-telegram-bot это была бы контекстная информация по юзеру (тот же словарь, но [хранит инфу по текущему юзера](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/79868614fb14eaca530a4b9b3361255817ed1f99/telegram_bot_examples/user_data__PicklePersistence/main.py#L34)). Вы можете хранить об этом в каком нибудь глобальном словаре, где ключом будет chat_id, а значением флаг обработки (в дальнейшем это можно переписать на базу данных)

Comment: В целом интересный вариант, а как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=10)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['today'])
async def today_handler(message: types.Message):
global last_time, count
if (datetime.now() - last_time).seconds < 10:
    return
date_message = f'Сегодня {datetime.now()}'
await message.answer(date_message)
last_time = datetime.now()
```

Для меня сработала такая конструкция для заморозки бота на 10 секунд
(если время сейчас отличается от последнего времени запроса к боту меньше чем на 10 сек - бот ничего не делает)

Comment: если кто вдруг зацепился глазом за переменную count - я её вводил чтобы считать количество сообщений боту во время остановки. Больше 5 - бот блочится на 10 минут.